# How to transform a variadic template argument to another types for calling another function?

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates

Function `f` receives arguments that can be transform to `Wrapper` using  `transform` function and it must call `f2`. `f2` receives a varidic number of Wrapper like arguments.

```
template <typename T>
Wrapper transform(T&& value) {
    return Wrapper(std::forward<T>(value));
}

template <typename... Args>
Wrapper f2(Args&&... args) {
    // All arguments must be Wrappers
    // More code
}

template <typename... Args>
Wrapper f(Args&&... args) {
    // Arguments can be transform to Wrapper using a transform function.
    return  f2( /* For each arg in args -> transform(std::forward<Args>(args)...)*/ ); // Problem!
}
```

The normal is to transform the parameters before and calling directly `f2` but I do not want to expose `transform` function to public.

Is there a way to achieve this, without expose `transform` function?

Comment: Have you tried return f2(transform(std::forward<Args>(args))...)?

Comment: @chema989 - sorry but I don't undestand... the suggestion from linuxfever seems me correct: with `f2(transform(std::forward<Args>(args))...)`, `f2()` is called with a sequence of `wrapper`s and match perfectly your `f2()` signature.

Comment: @max66 I'll check your answer.

Comment: @chema989 - added another solution in my answer (also C++11)

Comment: Thanks @linuxfever. I used `transform(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` only need to change by `transform(std::forward<Args>(args))...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to achieve this, without expose transform function?

What about using a lambda function?

```
template <typename... Args>
Wrapper f(Args&&... args)
 {
   static const auto tf = [](auto && value)
    { return Wrapper(std::forward<decltype(value)>(value)); };

   return f2( tf(std::forward<Args>(args)) ... );
 }
```

Observe that you tagged C++14 so you can use `auto` arguments in lambda functions

Another solution (also C++11) can be the use of a functor (`fc` instead `f`)

```
class fc
 {
   private:
      template <typename T>
      Wrapper transform (T && value)
       { return Wrapper(std::forward<T>(value)); }

   public:
      template <typename... Args>
      Wrapper operator() (Args&&... args)
       { return f2( transform(std::forward<Args>(args)) ... ); }
 };
```

But the use is slightly different: you can create a temporary object (but using another couple of parentheses

```
fc()(1, "abc", 2.3f);
```

or you can create an object of type `fc` and use it as a function

```
fc f0;

f0(1, "abc", 2.3f);
```

Comment: Thanks @max66.  I am using `C++14`. The lambda function is a good choice.

Comment: sorry: the downvoter can explain the downwote, please?

Answer (score 2):

Pack expansion can apply to arbitrarily complex expressions. In here:

```
return  f2( /* For each arg in args -> transform(std::forward<Args>(args)...)*/ ); // Problem!
```

The problem is that you're expanding *inside of `transform`*... that's the equivalent of writing `f2(transform(a0, a1, a2, ..., aN))`. Hopefully it's clear why that's wrong. You want the expression you're expanding to *include* the `transform`. That is:

```
return  f2(transform(std::forward<Args>(args))...);
```

Which expands into `f2(transform(a0), transform(a1), ..., transform(aN))`.

Comment: Yes it was my error, the pack expansion must be include `transform`. Thanks @Barry